# What Does Question Mark Mean in Xcode Project Navigator?

Tags: xcode, version-control

In the project navigator in Xcode, I am not sure what the ? is trying to tell me next to the file name.

[image: Screen Shot]

I am sure it is not a coincidence that this is the same file that I dragged from my root directory for the project to the Classes folder (because the .mm file was there and I wanted them to be together). The project still compiles just fine, however my code sense broke recently and I am wondering whether this may be part of the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 183, accepted):

It's the file untracked by source control.

Comment: If you use source control, it would probably make sense to add it.

Comment: Thanks. In case someone else reads this, just right click on the file and goto Source Control->Add. This will turn ? to A. So, basically: ? means not part of source control. A means added to source control, but not modified. M means it is added to source control and is modified.

Comment: Also, if you see the question mark against a file that you know *is* tracked, and the Source Control->Refresh Status menu option doesn't change anything, try just quitting and restarting Xcode. Sigh.

Comment: If above all didn't work, just throw your mac away, then step on it, then restart, and while it restarting, hit it with a hammer. If your mac make it this far, try reopening XCode. If that didn't work, you know what to do.

Comment: Wasn't using Source Control on my project but restarting Xcode (12 beta) fixed the problem. Thanks @MattGibson

Answer (score 86):

Those characters refer to the source control.

---

- **?** - Unversioned
- **M** - Modified
- **A** - Added
- **A+** - Moved/Renamed (**R** as of Xcode 13)
- **U** - Newer version of a file on source control

---

More reference [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html)

Comment: why the file is not automatically versioned ??

Answer (score 29):

You can add to source control by selecting the untracked files
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Following steps resolved issue for me:

- Select all your files with "?"
- Right click and select **Source Control**
- Select **Add Selected Files**
- Select **Commit Selected Files...**
- On the popup dialog just drop some comment (no matter what=)

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcTVz.png)

Answer (score 4):

Those are uncommitted files if your using GIT, you need to right click Source Control>Commit Selected File manually. It should take away the "?" on the new version of Xcode 6.3.2 as of today

Answer (score 2):

Along with all other answers. This shouldn't happen by default UNLESS you have changed the settings in Xcode.

From Xcode Preferences >> Source Control >> make sure 'Add and remove files automatically' is **selected**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Stage` the `Unstaged` file, if its a working copy and the `?` will change to `A`

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly get one my file `Unversioned` (with ? mark), but it was old file.

It was .m file. Before problem occurred, I created copy of it, for making new similar class. I renamed a class and add new file to XCode.

Problem (with old file become Unversioned) was in not renamed comment string at beginning:

```
//
//  MyFirstClass.m
```

When I renamed it, problem with Unversioned file was resolved.

```
//
//  MySecondClass.m
```

Hope it'll helpful somebody.

P.S. Additionally maybe needed to remove and copy back this files.