# Problem with getting text from a .txt file in c++ using fstream

Tags: c++, file

[image: This][And this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Vgl.jpg)I am trying to get the things written in a .txt file called CodeHere.txt and here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string line;
    string lines[100];
    ifstream myfile ("CodeHere.txt");
    int i = 0;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
      while ( getline (myfile,line) )
      {
          lines[0] = line;
          i++;
          
      }
      myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    
    cout << lines[0];
    
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is: Writing this to a file.Program ended with exit code: 0

But in my CodeHere.txt it has: hello

I tried saving it, but the result didn't change. I'm not sure whats going on. Can anyone help?

Comment: *"And the output is: Writing this to a file..."*. I don't see how that's possible. Please show the exact code that you're running.

Comment: I put the pictures one is auto showing and for the other click the link. @cigien

Comment: lines[i] = line; cout<<lines;  but we are just reading from a file.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Seems to work [fine](https://onlinegdb.com/B1ZQGPx7v). Are you sure you're compiling and running the correct program? I don't see where *Writing this to a file* is could come from.

Comment: I tried cropping your image, with only the code, then pasting into my IDE.  My IDE doesn't accept pictures, so I can't help you.  Maybe if you removed the picture and paste the exact text of your program, I can help.

Comment: I put cout << "testing"; and it worked so I'm sure its running the right project and file. @cigien

Comment: Why are you **always** overwriting location 0 of your array?  You should probably use an index variable and increment the index after each line read.

Comment: I have put the code as text @ThomasMatthews can you not see it?

Comment: Is this your correct code?  I don't see where the phrase "Writing this to a file" is printed (outputed).  I don't see where you write to a file.

Comment: This is genuinely strange, I also tried putting it on the 10th value of the array but it still gave the same result @ThomasMatthews. And also did you notice there is a question mark next to the txt file, do you know what that means?

Comment: Remove the second `myfile.close()` and see if that works. You don't have to manually call `close` anyway.

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: To be blunt, change `lines[0] = line` to `lines[i] = line`.

Comment: The `cout << lines[0]` will only print the first string in the array.

Comment: I don't see any question marks in your code pasted as text.

Comment: Yeah I know, i made in lines[0] because i was just entering one line anyway, I was gonna change that later

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, the program will only print the first string. But OP is claiming that it doesn't even do that.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Look at the picture and on the file hierarchy next to CodeHere.txt

Comment: The whole point is that I **can't** read the picture.  It's not coming out clearly on my small screen.  This is one reason, you need to remove it and edit your text version appropriately.

Comment: If you're using xcode, don't worry about the question mark. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525177/what-does-question-mark-mean-in-xcode-project-navigator

Comment: Im not exactly sure what to do know should i create a new file and try again?

Comment: @Omer: yes I believe it is the text file. Try not to copy and paste but type *Hello* yourself into a new text file, perhaps there is some weird end-of-line invisible symbol your editor inserts into the txt file that ifstream is not able to recognize.

Comment: Nope it still doesn't work but there is something i noticed. I took fjcop s answer and it tells you the line count and i went to the file and added some extra lines and it didnt show @Lingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your .txt file is in the same repertory? To me, it just looks like you entered the path wrong. Try with the absolute path (full one). Another option is that you haven't saved the text file yet, you're just editing it, and so it is in fact empty, that would be why your cout doesn't print anything.

Comment: It was probably reading the wrong file. I was messing around before this and may have created a invisible file which it thought it should read. When i gave the full path it worked

Comment: @Omer: the text file should be in the same folder of the c++ project, if you want to avoid having to give the full path to ifstream

Comment: @Omer I'm glad you got it figured out! If you want to use a relative path, be carefull. Depending on your IDE, the path may end up relative to your source code (as intended) or relative to the compiled code (probably not in the same directory /!\\).

Answer (score 1):

This should work, using a `vector<string>` to store the lines read from file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string line;
    vector<string> lines;
    ifstream myfile ("CodeHere.txt");
    int i = 0;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline(myfile, line) )
        {
             lines.push_back(line);
             i++;       
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << lines[0] << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope , I think it's a bug, it shows the exact same thing. There must be a problem with the file or xcode. And also did you notice there is a question mark next to the txt file, do you know what that means?

Comment: Test the program with some other text file. It works fine on my computer, reads any first line of any .txt file I tried with success.

Comment: Both your code and the OP's code will only output the first line that was read in.

Comment: If you are using `std::vector`, you don't need the `i` variable.

Comment: The question mark is perhaps due to your IDE not recognizing .txt files. It sees only .cpp, .h, .py and the like, source code files

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: you are right in both instances, the code will output the first line only, and the `i` is useless, but I am not the author so I don't know whether this will be used in some ways that will require to leave the oddities where they are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  vector<string> lines;
  if (file.is_open()) {
    // read all lines from the file
    std::string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
      lines.emplace_back(line);
    }
    file.close();
  }
  else {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    return -1;
  }
  cout << "file has " << lines.size() << " lines." << endl;
  for (auto l : lines) {
    cout << l << endl;
  }
```

Comment: file has 1 lines.
Writing this to a file.
Program ended with exit code: 0 still doesn't work I'm gonna use another IDE i think there is a problem with Xcode